# Add/set title of an <li> element

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to add/change the title value of this li Objects "test1" or "test2".
It is not possible to set title like this:

```
test1.title = "hello";
test2.title = "juhu";

<li ID="test1" runat="server" class="none"></li>
<li ID="test2" runat="server" title="test" class="none"></li>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to assign these attributes from the server side code then you need to use the Attributes properties of the html control.

```
test1.Attributes["title"] = "hello";
test2.Attributes["title"] = "juhu";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
test1.Attributes.Add("title","hello");
test2.Attributes.Add("title","juhu");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
    <li Id="test1" runat="server" class="none" title="hello" ></li>
```

Comment: No I want to change the title with c#! dynamically

Comment: Go for the other answer posted by jurgis. It will do your job.

Comment: @SigiAnonym you should mention C# in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does objects "test1" and "test2" exist AND have properties "title"?

If they do, you can set the titles as:

```
<li ID="test2" runat="server" title="@test1.title" class="none"></li>
```

Note the object-style call to variable and the "@" - it tells razor to expect c# value.

Also, as far as I know, title is not a valid html5 element. Use data-title = ".."

Comment: Yes both have properties "title", but not at C#. I will try your answer.

Comment: I will try maybe about something like this test1.Attributes.Add("title", "test").